# Flutter ListView itembuilder won't show anything. Why?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I wanted to display multiple ListTiles using the ListView.itembuilder in Flutter. I did it, but the screen is still blank. Tried hot reloading as well as running the app twice. What's wrong in the code?

P.S: The List is going to appear in my TabBarView that I created earlier. Also posting the snipper of the TabBarView.

**ListView code:**

```
class SportBets extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _SportBetsState createState() => _SportBetsState();
}

class _SportBetsState extends State<SportBets> {

    final sportList = [
        "Basketball",
        "Football",
        "Volleyball",
    ];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: sportList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    ListTile(
                        title: Text(sportList[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),),
                        trailing: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: (){}
                        ),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny),radius: 18.0,),
                    );
                }
            );
    }
}
```

**TabBarView Code:**

```
body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                        "Highlights Page here",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                ),
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                        "Casino Page here",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                ),
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                        "Promotions Page here",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                ),
                SportBets(),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: `return ListTile` - now you are not returning anything from `itemBuilder`

Comment: Thanks this worked! One more question though. Now that there's an IconButton for every ListTile, how do I navigate to a separate page on pressing them each?

Comment: sure, youre welcome, you have `index` in `itemBuilder` - so you need to use it somehow when you want to navigate to the next page

Answer (score 0):

Some errors you need to fix

1. Add a `return` statement in the `itemBuilder` of `ListView`
2. Wrap your `TabBarView` with a `DefaultTabContoller` and set `DefaultTabContoller`'s length as 4 as you have 4 tabs.